# Is there an editor for building web UIs using JavaScript frameworks like jQueryUI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, javascript-framework, sencha-architect

Is there an editor that can build web based UIs using a JavaScript framework like jQuery (jQueryUI)? The desirable editor should allow me to do page layouts and templates. Then I should be able to organize my content and forms and apply requisite CSS and of course this should be cross browser.

I have checked Sencha Architect http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/ that uses the ExtJS framework but it falls well short of my expectations and of course it honors only ExtJs.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be SoL on this one.  That type of editor is nearly impossible to find for front-end web dev.  Although, you can tie jQuery and jQueryUI into [**Komodo Edit**](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) and have "IntelliSense" style coding throughout your application and ... it's free!

Comment: What's wrong with Visual Studio? :)

Comment: @mattytommo, I'm not sure if I was clear enough, but I want a professional quality of WYSIWYG editor. Since you've mentioned Visual Studio, can I build UIs in Visual Studio using jQueryUI with in design mode with right degree of precision?

Answer (score 0):

Maquetta it is based in dojotoolkit.org but you will need a ibm user to log into it

Comment: Please note that Maquetta is not actively developed any more by IBM: see e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/maqetta-users/dLGzdERrkG8/PQ9Xv25eRD8J